# how to clear SafeHtmlBuilder value

Tags: gwt

I am using SafeHtmlBuilder i my GWT/GXT application ,
We have set someloading icon in it and then later in few seconds i like to remove that loading icon and display some other icon.

But i am not able to clear that loading icon

is there a way ..

```
             render(Context context, SymbolDTO value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb)
              {
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div style=\"cursor: pointer;\"> " + symbolStr2 + "</div>");

            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div style=\"cursor: pointer;\"> " + symbolStr3 + "</div>");
```

so when i insert symbolstr3, it displays symbol2 and symbol3 , but how i can first remove symbol2 and only display symbol3 here..

Comment: add an id tag or css class to the div to toggle visibility

Comment: i dont want to make it invisible , i just want to replace the content

Comment: `DOM.getElementById("...").setInnerSafeHtml(...)`

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is create a new SafeHtmlBuilder instance when you want to start fresh, SafeHtmlBuilder isnt a widget, is it from its name a way to cosntruct html string literals to be used later as html content for other widgets or elements.

So in your case depending on from where you are passing that SafeHtmlBuilder you might better return a new builder instance in the that method, or pass a new instance of SafeHtmlBuilder, and when you execute that method you simply clear the target element and set its content with the html from the builder by calling the toSafeHtml and get the html string from it.